# Android: Mediaplayer launches like a rocket, gone

Tags: android, android-appwidget

i am trying to create a streaming media player widget. I am able to get it playing, but pushing stop gives (or gave) me a NullpointerException (but PAUSE and STOP do show up nicely in Logcat). So the Mediaplayer launches away and it is gone, with me unable to grab it back. It must be something small that i am doing wrong, but i just can't get my finger behind it. Any idea?

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider implements
MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener {

    public static String PLAY = "Play";
    public static String STOP = "Stop";
    public static String PAUSE = "Pause";

     private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
     private MediaPlayer mp;

     @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

        Intent play = new Intent(context, MyWidget.class);
        play.setAction(PLAY);
        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, play, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.play, actionPendingIntent);

        play = new Intent(context, MyWidget.class);
        play.setAction(PAUSE);
        actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, play, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.pause, actionPendingIntent);

        play = new Intent(context, MyWidget.class);
        play.setAction(STOP);
        actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, play, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.stop, actionPendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(PLAY)) {
            Log.i("onReceive", PLAY);
            play();

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(PAUSE)) {
            Log.i("onReceive", PAUSE);
            pause();

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(STOP)) {
            Log.i("onReceive", STOP);
            stop();

        } else {
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }


    }

    private void play() {

             try {
           if (mp == null) {
            this.mp = new MediaPlayer();
           } else {
            mp.stop();
            mp.reset();
           }
           mp.setDataSource("MyURL"); // Go to Initialized state
           mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
           mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
           mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);

           mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
           mp.prepareAsync();

           Log.d(TAG, "LoadClip Done");
          } catch (Throwable t) {
           Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
          }
         }

         public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Stream is prepared");
          try {
          mp.start();
          } catch (Exception e) {
          // 
          }
         }

         private void pause() {
          try {
             mp.pause();
         } catch (Exception e) {
              //
              }
         }

         private void stop() {

             try {
             mp.stop();
             mp.reset();
         } catch (Exception e) {
              // 
              }

         }

         public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
          stop();
         }

         public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          sb.append("Media Player Error: ");
          switch (what) {
          case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
           sb.append("Not Valid for Progressive Playback");
           break;
          case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
           sb.append("Server Died");
           break;
          case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
           sb.append("Unknown");
           break;
          default:
           sb.append(" Non standard (");
           sb.append(what);
           sb.append(")");
          }
          sb.append(" (" + what + ") ");
          sb.append(extra);
          Log.e(TAG, sb.toString());
          return true;
         }

         public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
          Log.d(TAG, "PlayerService onBufferingUpdate : " + percent + "%");
         }

            }
```

EDIT: (edit undone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have found the answer myself: it is not possible to build a media player like i wanted to with the code above. I decided to put the player functionality in a service and it works like a charm now. Case closed!

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion based on success in my own app, try putting the appWidgetId and PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT in as getBroadcast parameters:

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, play, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

You'll need to loop through the appWidgetIds array of course.

Comment: Thanks Matt, what exactly do you mean with "loop through the appWidgetIds array" ? I presume it has something to do with the fact that in my current code the AppWidgetId needs to be an Integer? Thanks!